# Paralells Desktop changes default Application to play .mp4 files

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, quicktime

Even though I have selected the option "Always Open with" Quicktime Player for my .mp4 files. The changes never take effect and instead when I open a video, parallels desktop launches Windows Media Player.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried same with Info (Cmd-I). This is better way to change default program. Also I've stopped sharing anything else than folders between Windows & Mac since upgraded to Parallels Desktop 7. It helps much also.

Comment: yes! this method actually worked. THanks a lot, appreciate it.

Comment: So I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried same with Info (Cmd-I). This is better way to change default program. Also I've stopped sharing anything else than folders between Windows & Mac since upgraded to Parallels Desktop 7. It helps much also.